# Declaring Objects from different ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, declaration

In my application, I have a ViewController (ViewController 1) that has a UITextField and a UIButton. In my ViewController 2, I have a UINavigationBar. I want to be able to type something in the ViewController 1 textfield, press the button, then have the UINavigationBar text in ViewController 2 be set as the UITextField from ViewController 1. But of course, Xcode will not let you declare objects from another ViewController without doing more work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but from what I could understand you want a `ViewController`'s `UIButton` to set the `NavigationBar`'s title of a second `ViewController`?

Seems like a pretty weird behavior to me but here's what I think might help you.

On your first `ViewController` create a protocol/delegate functionality so that when your `UIButton` is pressed you can call:

```
-(IBAction) changeTitle:(id) sender {    
[self.delegate buttonPressed:txtView.text];
}
```

And with that send your `UITextField`'s text to your `AppDelegate`, or whoever creates these two `ViewControllers`, and there you will receive that text and send it to your second `ViewController`.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(NSString *)text{
secondViewController.title = text;
}
```

Perhaps you will have to implement a method that changes the title in your second `ViewController` if that line does not work. Hope this is useful for you and that I understood your question.

Comment: Here's an example of a protocol.  `@protocol myDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) buttonPressed: (NSString *) text;
@end` [Basics of Protocols](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but the following should work for you:

```
navBar.topItem.title = @"title";
```

OR

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"title";
```

@"title" will be replaced with the string variable (in VC2) that was set before pushing VC2 in the navigationcontroller stack....

cheers

Comment: Wait, so how would this all work? I understand what you are saying, but where would I declare all of this? I just need more details.

Comment: Setting the text is what I'm not concerned about, I just need to declare the UINavigationBar from ViewController 2 so that when I'm writing the code in ViewController 1 I can use the naviBar from ViewController 2 if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Oscar's answer but if this is a string you want multiple view controllers to have access to then you might set a property in your app delegate.

```
In AppDelegate
@property (NSString *) myString;

In View Controller setting
myAppDelegate *appDelegate =  (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.myString = @"meh"; 

In View Controller getting
myAppDelegate *appDelegate=  (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *mehStr = appDelegate.myString;
```

It's not the full code, but you get the idea. I'm not sure I would go overboard sending stuff back to the appdelegate but for one string it should work fine.